# How to make Java REST API GET Request using Retrofit2.0?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using **Retrofit2.0** for making `GET` request to my *REST URL*. I don't need to pass any params to url for making the request. 
How could on can make this type of request?

Here is my code what i 've done!

Interface ::

```
public interface AllRolesAPI {
    @GET("/SportsApp/allroles")
    Call<AllRolesParams> getAllRoles();
}
```

Class ::: 
   I created a class using Pojo library it contains all the variables with setter and getter methods.

```
public void requestRoles() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
                .build();

        AllRolesAPI allRolesParams = retrofit.create(AllRolesAPI.class);
        Call<AllRolesParams> allRolesParamsCall = allRolesParams.getAllRoles();
        allRolesParamsCall.enqueue(new Callback<AllRolesParams>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AllRolesParams> call, Response<AllRolesParams> response) {
                //response.body().getErrDesc();
                Log.v("SignupActivity", "Response :: " + response.body().getErrDesc());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AllRolesParams> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.v("SignupActivity", "Failure :: ");
            }
        });
    }
```

When I create a request like above I have got this error in console ::

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.acknotech.kiran.navigationdrawer.AllRolesParams.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your API's responses are JSON, you need to add

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

In order to be able to use GsonConverterFactory, you need to add a gradle dependency. Check [this](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). In your case is

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

(2.1.0 is the latest version at the time of this writing)

Comment: When i change the code like what you said... enqueue shows the error, like cannot find the symbol.

Comment: yes, because you need to add that dependency to the build.gradle file, and sync the project

Comment: No.. still getting error.

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    AllRolesAPI allRolesAPI = retrofit.create(AllRolesAPI.class);

    Call<AllRolesParams> allrolesResponseCall = allRolesAPI.getAllRoles();

This is what the code now how should i make the get request without any  parameter passing.

Comment: Add the complete stack trace

Comment: AllRolesAPI
public interface AllRolesAPI {
    @GET("/SportsApp/allroles")
    Call<AllRolesParams> getAllRoles();
}

AllRolesParams.java
Have setter and getters methods of response params.

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() .baseUrl(ENDPOINT) .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) .build(); AllRolesAPI allRolesAPI = retrofit.create(AllRolesAPI.class); Call<AllRolesParams> allrolesResponseCall = allRolesAPI.getAllRoles(); 

This is the full stack trace.

Comment: no, this is the code.. I mean the error stack trace.. this is only a part of it (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.acknotech.kiran.navigationdrawer.AllRolesParams.) please all the complete stack

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your honourable concern.
I can't even compile the code it shows errors in code only.
like, .. . i think request body what i made is wrong. Searching for how to write get request body for Retrofit2.0

Comment: This is the request body i have... with errors
allrolesResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<AllRolesParams>() {
        public void onResponse(Call<AllRolesParams> call, Response<AllRolesParams> response) {

            Log.d("SignupActivity", "session id is ... :: " + session_id);

            Log.d("MainActivity", "onResponse: " + statuscode);
        }
        public void onFailure(Call<AllRolesParams> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());

            onSignupFailed();
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

Quoting official docs:

> By default, Retrofit can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's
>   ResponseBody type and it can only accept its RequestBody type for
>   @Body. Converters can be added to support other types. Six sibling
>   modules adapt popular serialization libraries for your convenience.
>
> Gson: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson
>   Jackson:com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson
>   Moshi:com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi
>   Protobuf:com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-protobuf
>   Wire:com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-wire
>   Simple XML:com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml 
>   Scalars (primitives, boxed,and String): com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars

You are trying to parse JSON without any converter. There are various converts you can use with Retrofit. Most Popular is Gson Converter from Google. To make your code work create Retrofit adapter like this:

```
adapter = new Retrofit.Builder() //in your case replace adapter with Retrofit retrofit
.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```

Also make sure to include these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'      
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'       
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Hope it works.You can refer to [official retrofit docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/),[this guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) and [gson guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) for more information.